# 'System.Web.Webpages.Html.Htmlhelper' does not contain a definition for 'Sitecore'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.2

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio, when I use `@Html.Sitecore`:

> 'System.Web.Webpages.Html.Htmlhelper' does not contain a definition for 'Sitecore' and the best extension methods overload 'Sitecore.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions.Sitecore(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' has some invalid arguments.`

However, once deployed it does run without any problems.

I'm using Sitecore 7.2 with MVC 5.1.

[image]

Articles that I've read that deal with similar error messages, talk about the `system.web.webPages.razor` section of the `Views` folder `web.config` file. This is how it appears in my solution.

```xml
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Originally I thought I'd just need to restart VS, but that didn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions.

**EDIT**
This is the standard Sitecore 7.2 installation, and so has the following binding redirects:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Also when looking at the output from visual studio there is an additional error that I didn't spot before:

`Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' to 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'`

**EDIT 2**

I no longer think this is a Sitecore MVC issue. I get a similar error with `@Html.ActionLink("xxx", "xxx")`. Other people have seen this issue in VS2012, but  I'm using 2013.

**EDIT 3**

There are now quite a few answers to this question. I recommend trying each of them as it seems there are numerous reasons this error might occur.

Comment: Here was solved similar problem: [Stackoverflow solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now resolved this issue. I simply had to install Update 2 of Visual Studio 2013. How frustrating.

Thanks to StriplingWarrior and Ahmed Okour for your useful advice.

Comment: I summarised this in a blog post: http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.com/2014/06/preparing-sitecore-72-and-mvc-in-visual.html

Comment: Yes this solution works fine also for me. I spend hours on investigating web.config files but finally Update 5 solve the problem.

Answer (score 19):

I have the same problem a while ago. We found out that we are missing the web.config inside /views folder. we copy a web.config from my other projects' /views and it solved the issue.

Comment: The `/views/web.config` file was already present in my case, but thanks.

Comment: I'd also popped a razor file in the layouts folder which was causing my beef. So to be clear you need to either keep all razor files in the views folder OR add a web.config wherever you plonk any razor views.

Answer (score 17):

Try This, then try to restart visual studio.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

You forgot to add  `<add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc" />` so that intellisense can pick it up in VS.

Comment: True, but he does have `@using SiteCore.Mvc` at the top of his razor view, so I don't think this will fix the problem.

Comment: I did try adding it to the config too, but it didn't help. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Then this should a visual studio issue, Not Sitecore, try this on different machine

Comment: For VS 2013, follow Martin's answer about updating to Update 2.
You will also need to have the appropriate App_Config files within your project directory (not necessarily included in your project though) Here's my post on it:- http://www.seanholmesby.com/fixing-visual-studio-intellisense-in-sitecore-mvc-views/

Answer (score 5):

I have used the below line at the top and the issue has been resolved.

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
```

Answer (score 3):

You say you're using MVC 5, but you're referencing version 3 in the code you provided. Here's what mine says:

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Try checking through your entire web.config file (or all the web.config files if you have multiple Areas) and making sure that all the versions are set right. For MVC 5, `System.Web.WebPages` should be on version 2 and System.Web.WebPages.Razor should be on version 3.

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

...

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a standard Sitecore 7.2 installation, and so has assembly binding redirects for `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` and `System.Web.Mvc` (See my updates to the question.). However. I did follow your suggestions, but unfortunately they didn't make a difference.

Comment: [This guy](http://kamsar.net/index.php/2013/12/using-mvc-5-with-sitecore-7-1/) apparently also recommends commenting out the razor `<sectionGroup>`. Have you done that?

Comment: Tried that too, but no luck. Think this might be one for Sitecore Support.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its the silly things. Check you're not doing something like

```
@Html.Sitecore("placeholdername")   // no method
```

or

```
@Html.Sitcore.Placeholder("placeholdername") // Missing parenthesis
```

when you should be doing

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("placeholdername") // this works
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
    <add namespace="Telerik.Reporting" />
  </namespaces>
```

Comment: First go to the (reference-->Add reference) and Add kendo.Mvc.dll then after go to the view file and edit webconfig file as above mention

Answer (score -1):

I have added Sitecore.Mvc dll in references with copy local to true and added below tag in view's web.config under namespaces tag, then my problem is resolved.