# Sitecore Intellisense broken under website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-instance-manager

I installed a sitecore instance with SIM, and checked the project for a MVC solution, what I don't get is why the @Html.**Sitecore()** is not working:

```
Error   2   'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Sitecore' and no extension method 'Sitecore' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have the /Views/Web.config with the following:

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
```

Is there something different that needs to be done when running a solution inside the "Website" folder vs publishing to the Website folder?

Comment: Your project needs to reference Sitecore.Kernel and Sitecore.Mvc dlls

Comment: Those DLL's are in the references folder and are also in the /bin

Comment: Which Sitecore version you use exactly?

Comment: Went through this a while back. This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147846/system-web-webpages-html-htmlhelper-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-sitecor

Comment: Sitecore version 7.5 (latest), VS 2013 V4 MVC4

Comment: Have you found the solution?  We are also facing the same Issue. Sitecore 8.0, MVC 5, VS 2013 V3. I have already tried the options suggested in Sean Holmesby's Blog. But nothing works. The pages are displaying fine on browser. Issue is with the Intellisense only.

Comment: go to references locate sitecore.mvc > properties > set copy local to true

Comment: I am preserving the following link in case it is deleted from an answer: http://www.seanholmesby.com/fixing-visual-studio-intellisense-in-sitecore-mvc-views/