# .net mvc change html helper class

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In razor template engine i'm using html helper class.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to change Html class from `System.Web.Webpage.Html` to `System.Web.Mvc.Html`.

i added following configurations to view web.config file.

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="temp" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

it still comes from under System.Web.Webpage.Html. 
How can i change library to Mvc.Html helper?

Comment: reload doesn't help? From this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23389635/1849444). **Then: 1=>2=>3=>4=>5**

Comment: I tried but not working.