# Problems with MVC and Visual Studio 2015 - No HTML Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I have issues with Visual Studio 2015 and MVC since I downloaded it.  The problem is made worse as it seems no one else is having this issue yet I'm having this issue on multiple computers.

If I create a new project MVC in VS 2015 Community Edition, I do

1. File -> New Project
2. Web -> ASP.NET Web Application
3. I choose MVC 'icon' and underneath I check only the MVC check box.

A default application loads, but I can see all the HTML helpers in the HTML pages are underlined. This means no intellesense. As you can see, this is with a new project.

EG, the `@Html.ViewBag.Title`  is underlined, if I type in `@Html.` I get no intellesense.

I assume (based upon what the web.config file shows) that this is MVC 5.

I manually added

```
 <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
```

I cleaned and then rebuilt.

I deleted all bins.

I restart Visual Studio (even PC).

`update-package`

Delete the .user file that Visual Studio generated next to the project.

Unloading/reloading project

When I hover over the HTML, I see the following

[image]

I can type the syntax and providing the syntax is correct, the helper is working but, `Model` does not exist in the following

```
    @model Project.Bll.Models.ProjectPlan
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.DateFormat, Model.DateFormats)
    }
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you try the things suggested here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper

Comment: @OlaEkdahl, sadly yes :(

Comment: This is for VS2012 but might fix the intellisense issue for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken

Comment: Thanks @OlaEkdahl but still no luck!!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper