# IDE to develop MVC 3 and build Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2017

I'm on VS 2017 (or Version 15.2) and I'm trying to open a MVC3 project.

The project build and run fine, but in edit mode the compiler keep giving me those errors.

> 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'HiddenFor' and no
>   extension method 'HiddenFor' accepting a first argument of type
>   'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Side effect of this, intellisence does not work in my Views.

Is there a way to fix those error in VS2017 or can I use an other IDE?

Comment: See if this solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23389635/2990310

Comment: Allready tried that. The solution seam to work with MVC5. I'm on MVC3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC3 is not supported after VS2010.
So just use MVC's latest iteration, 5

Comment: Saddly this is not a solution. The requirement of the project is MVC 3.

Comment: Get VS2010 then..there is no other way.

Comment: VS2010SP1 Pack does work fine for me , so check it out.