# Asp.Net MVC - Trying to get Html.RenderAction to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

So I've been trying to figure out a way to use a Model called Posts in my layout for a few days now, and a solution (that would be perfect if it worked for me) was:

```
@Html.RenderAction()
```

Which gave me an error of:

> 'IHtmlHelper>' does not contain a definition for 'RenderAction' and no extension method 'RenderAction' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried fixing it the error by adding the following to the web.config file, but it doesn't change a thing,

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

trying `using System.Web` doesn't do anything because the namespace "Web" doesn't exist in  "System".

Is there anything I can change to use the Html.RenderAction() method?

Comment: Did you try restarting VS and clean and rebuild?

Comment: `RenderAction` expects at least a string with the action name.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx
Are you trying to access a view model in the site's layout? There are other questions about that explaining that that's not possible and also you shouldn't.

Comment: If this is not related with how to use `RenderAction` as Andrew said, check for possible symptoms here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper. IIRC `RenderAction` bounds to action name (& controller name) where action executes depending on parameters used.

Comment: You need to tag your questions correctly.