# Razor View showing Htmlhelper does not contain a definition for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac

I have been using VS for Mac for a while. But I always getting the following warning messages in my views:

'HtmlHelper' doesn't contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and not accessible extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Same thing happens for other controls: BeginForm, AntiForgeryToken, Partial, etc...

[image]

These are the settings I have in the ./View/Web.config:

[image]

...and this for the Web.config at the solution level:

[image]

I have been doing a search how to solve this and following this link [Razor Views not seeing System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper)
, but not luck as of now. Any help or clue how to fix this?

Comment: Delete the `bin` and `obj` folders of the projects and rebuild. Error should go away.

Comment: Please post the code instead of images of code. See [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged/320060#320060) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for MVC 5.2.7:

1. Create a new MVC web application from Visual Studio
2. Copy the Web.config configuration from the Views folder over to your working application's Views folder and do the same for the root web.config
3. Also ensure your MVC project file (.proj file) has the following after TargetFrameworkVersion element `<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>`

After following these steps, intellisense began to work.